# Hide div when clicking outside

Tags: jquery, hide

I've searched and search not only google but also here and still have to find a solution that will work.

I have a div that is hidden by default, then toggled by clicking on a link. I also want it to hide when you click outside of the div. Simple, I thought, but nothing I've tried had worked yet.

This is the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleDiv(divID) {
    $("#"+divID).fadeToggle(200);
    }
</script>
```

And the link that toggles it:

```
<a onclick="toggleDiv('myDiv');">Link</a>
```

And then the div:

```
<div id="myDiv">
stuff
</div>
```

If anyone has any advice, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery you'll also want to attach you click event handler using jQuery facilities: $(document).ready(function() { $("#linkId").click(function() { // Do stuff }));

Answer (score 11):

This should do the trick for you:

```
var openDiv;

function toggleDiv(divID) {
    $("#" + divID).fadeToggle(200, function() {
        openDiv = $(this).is(':visible') ? divID : null;
    });
}

$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('#'+openDiv).length) {
        toggleDiv(openDiv);
    }
});
```

[**Example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/CHP5w/1/)

**EDIT:** Now works for all scenarios.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be a bit buggy when trying to have the same behavior with multiple, different divs.

Answer (score 3):

You can just a add click handler on `body` as a click anywhere will "bubble up" to this element.

```
$("body").click(function(){ $("#myDiv").fadeOut(200); });
```

You might also like to add a class on toggled elements in your demo code so you can target these more specifically when you want to hide them.

```
function toggleDiv(divID) {
    $("#"+divID).fadeToggle(200).toggleClass("visible");
}

$("body").click(function(){
    $(".visible").fadeOut(200, function(){
        $(this).removeClass("visible");
    });
});
```

If you don't want the visible `div` to hide when clicked itself you'll also need to cancel clicks on those elements, maybe using jQuery's `live()` method.

```
$(".visible").live("click", function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: You'll have to set a flag as to whether the click took place w/i the div or not. Inside, don't fade. Outside, fade.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
                var container = $("#form1");

                if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    container.hide();
                    $('#signupSection').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#signupSection2').css('display', 'block');
                }
            });
```